# How to execute functions asynchronously with SWOOLE?

Tags: swoole

I have heard promising words about php's [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk/) project. However, in their doc/examples, I only see the implementation of server handlings (i.e. how to setup webserver, answer requests, etc..). However, I was unable to find examples, how to simply fire an asynchronous functions from cli (i.e. `php myfile.php`)
where `myfile.php` might contain (with my undestranding) something like this `Swoole\SomeAsyncFunion` (just phseudo name):

```
Swoole\SomeAsyncFunion(  function(){ file_get_contents("http://site-1.com"); echo "hello";  }   );
Swoole\SomeAsyncFunion(  function(){ do_long_running_function(); echo "world"; }   ); 
Swoole\SomeAsyncFunion( .... ); 
Swoole\SomeAsyncFunion( .... ); 
Swoole\SomeAsyncFunion( .... );
```

So, just execute multiple functions in async from php-cli. How to do that? With `parallel` extension I exactly same as described (  `\parallel\run(  function(){ ... }   );`  ) but couldn't figure-out how to do with swoole. (i dont have a requirement of any web-server, just need cli).

Comment: found: https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-coroutine-run

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Co\run` and `go`

```php
use function Swoole\Coroutine\go;
use function Swoole\Coroutine\run;

run(function () {
    go(function () {
        file_get_contents("http://site-1.com"); echo "hello";
    });
    go(function () {
        do_long_running_function(); echo "world";
    });
});
```